# 64 bit overflow error in compiler or cpu

Tags: c++

Is this an error in the compiler or CPU, or is it *not* an error (I am using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows)?

I have this test program:

```
    {
    puts("===========================");
    puts("Long Long");

    long long maxInt = 0x7fffffffffffffff;

    if (maxInt * 1.0 + 0.5 > 0x7fffffffffffffff)
        puts("Greater");
    else
        puts("Not Greater");

    long long newVal = maxInt * 1.0 + 0.5;

    if (newVal == 0x8000000000000000)
        puts("It is 0x8000000000000000");
    else
        puts("is NOT 0x8000000000000000");
}

{
    puts("===========================");
    puts("int");

    int maxInt = 0x7fffffff;

    if (maxInt * 1.0 + 0.5 > 0x7fffffff)
        puts("Greater");
    else
        puts("Not Greater");

    int newVal = maxInt * 1.0 + 0.5;

    if (newVal == 0x80000000)
        puts("It is 0x80000000");
    else
        puts("is NOT 0x80000000");
}
```

When I run it I see this output:

```
===========================

Long Long

Not Greater

It is 0x8000000000000000

===========================

int

Greater

is NOT 0x80000000
```

I am assuming that the "greater than" comparisons are casting to `float`, or maybe `double`.  But when the first comparison says "Not Greater", then I expect the cast to 'long long', will get the `0x7fffffffffffffff` value instead of the overflow to `0x8000000000000000`.

With an `int` everything works as I would expect it to.

So why is the 64 bit behavior not what I expect?

Comment: It is not a compiler error, or a CPU error. The error is in your expectations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `double` only holds 53 bits of mantissa, while a `long long` holds 64. You're losing the bottom bits in the conversion. In fact they're being rounded, which is why you end up with 0x800000000.

Comment: That explains what happens here "if (maxInt * 1.0 + 0.5 > 0x7fffffffffffffff)" But it seems like the opposite is happening here:  "long long newVal = maxInt * 1.0 + 0.5;" I figured loss of precision would make that 2nd case be either 0x7fffffffffffffff or something less than 0x7fffffffffffffff.  So loss of precision does not explain the value that gets assigned.

Comment: Hmm, so what you are saying is that internally this "maxInt * 1.0 + 0.5 > 0x7fffffffffffffff" becomes "maxInt * 1.0 + 0.5 > 0x8000000000000000", which makes the greater than fail, right?  If so I now understand.

Comment: @Solx, yes that's correct. The promotion rules convert the right side of the `>` to double as well, which also gets rounded.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `0x7fffffffffffffff` cannot be represented exactly as a `double`. The nearest value that can be is `0x8000000000000000`.

This means that the moment you cast `0x7fffffffffffffff` to `double` it turns to `9223372036854775808.0`, or `0x8000000000000000`.